# Accessing Attributes from different Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models in a has_many relationship:

1. User `(has_many :vacations)`
2. Vacation `(belongs_to: user)`

I am trying to display a User's credits attribute in the Vacation index view. How do I go about it?

I have tried:
`<%= vacation.user.credits %>`, however, I am getting an error.

What are the right steps in doing so? Does it have anything to do with the Action Controller Parameters?

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :vacations
end
```

**Vacation Model**

```
class Vacation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_validation :calculate_days

  def calculate_days
    if from_date && to_date
      self.leave_credit = from_date.business_days_until(to_date) + 1
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show the way you are setting up the relationships in your models, as well as the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you share your code on github, and also possible to show the error that you are getting.

Comment: @sundayAdefila I have updated the original question.

Comment: so, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Jose where is your error? I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided; perhaps there's something fishy in the controller/view.

Comment: @TomLord how do I go about accessing the User attribute of credits in the Vacation Index view?

Comment: Can you check in your rails console if the vacation model is even associated to any user at all.

Comment: @Saad Are you talking about a JOIN table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be using the `current_user` method, since you're already using devise. This would work only if credits have to be displayed only to the currently logged in user, say in the dashboard. try using `<%= current_user.credits %>`

You could also try

```
class VacationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @credits = @user.credits
  end
end
```

Another one line approach could be

`@credits = User.find(params[:user_id]).credits`